# How to change url of specific posts with name of a root page

Tags: url-rewriting

So my client site will be used for filling in a form to anticipate on neighborhood question from town councils.

The homepage will be a town search page where you can type your town and go to a landing page of that town, for example, `domain.nl/city`.

From there everything needs to be found from `domain.nl/city`. So a post for that city will be `domain.nl/city/post1`. The contact page will be `domain.nl/city/contact`.

There will be different cities in the site.

I work with Avada theme so I can create a header for each city that will link only to specific pages.

I hear you saying, create a multi site! This I had and it had issues with certain certificates.

I have my base standing. The only thing to do now is the posts that need to have a base url with  the city name in front of it.

Please be gentle with me, it is my first question on stackexchange :-)

Comment: You could use the default wordpress categories and posts, or parent and child pages to achive this url structure, that's a start, the rest is up to you

Comment: You could also create custom post types, one for each city. That might provide an easier way to manage the different cities - you'd have for example a "Paris" menu item and a "London" menu item in wp-admin so it would be clear which city's content you're working on.

Comment: Ok, thanks for these suggestions. I will look into them.